# how to get root node with its attributes and without child nodes from XmlDocument using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml like:

```
<Customer id="">
 <Name />
 <Address />
</Customer>
```

I would like to select ONLY a root node header(not footer) with its attributes without its child nodes:

```
<Customer id="">
```

Comment: You want to get xml node as string?

Comment: Yes, i need the xml node as string. Because I need to add root node in another file as header and footer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Root` property if it is root element:

```
XDocument Doc = XDocument.Parse(StringXML);

var RootNode= Doc.Root;
string NodeName = RootNode.Name.ToString();
string AttributeValue = RootNode.Attribute("id").Value;
```

if there are multiple Customer nodes in the xml then you have to use linq:

```
var nodes = from customer in Doc.Descendants("Customer")
                         select new { 
                                     NodeName = customer.Name.ToString(),               
                                     Id = customer.Attribute("id").Value 
                                    };
```

### UPDATE:

For getting all attributes you can use `Attributes()` this way:

```
var nodess = from customer in Doc.Descendants("Customer")

             select new { 
                          NodeName = customer.Name.ToString(), 
                          Attributes = customer.Attributes() 
                        };
```

[WORKING DOTNET FIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCoFYE)

Comment: I have no of attributes..and names of attributes are not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to take this node as string, the you can use `Root` property, and then split root by `Environment.NewLine` and take the first one:

```
 XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(InnerXML);
 var result = xdoc.Root.ToString()
                       .Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                       .First();
```

The result is: `<Customer id="">`

***Additional1***:
 If you want to get all attributes names and values which belong to root, then you can use:

```
var rootAttributesDatas = xdoc.Root
                         .Attributes()
                         .Select(x => new { AttributeName = x.Name, AttributeValue = x.Value })
                         .ToList();
```

***Additional2***:
 If you have more than one `customer` node and want to select all datas about  them as a list:

```
var allCustomerNodeDatas = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Customer")
                           .Select(x => new
                            {
                                 NodeName = x.Name,
                                 AttributesDatas = x.Attributes().Select(attr => new
                                 {
                                     AttributeName = attr.Name,
                                     AttributeValue = attr.Value
                                 }).ToList()
                            }).ToList();
```